# Android WebView stopped working GIF-animation

Tags: android, webview

I have WebView

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layerType="software"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

And I load html with GIF

```
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/payPass.html");
```

before all worked, but now I noticed that the animation does not play. I do not understand what could be wrong

```
<html>
<body align='center'>
<img src="paypass.gif" align="center">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `paypass.gif` located?

Comment: file:///android_asset/paypass.gif

Comment: The picture is shown, but as a picture and not as a GIF

Comment: try using this https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score -1):

Maybe for the Android version.